# virt-manager riscv64 Debian install

Tags: debian, software-installation, virtual-machine, virt-manager

I am attempting to install Debian11 for riscv64 in Virtmanager for personal education purposes. I am using an x86 AMD processor in case that is needed info. After an amount of research I have not been able to find an image to use and neither have I been able to any way to boot any sort of image for a riscv64 installation. The only option I have found is this https://github.com/janvrany/riscv-debian but it is not necessarily a "Stable" or "Safe" option for making one from source.
If someone could provide instructions for making the image, that would be great.

Comment: Have you tried https://wiki.debian.org/RISC-V#Setting_up_a_riscv64_virtual_machine?

Comment: I never found that. I will upvote you if it works. Thanks!